# How to access react-bootstrap panel collapse state in panel title?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

When using the [react-bootstrap Collapsible Panel](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/panel/#panels-collapsible), is there any way to access the panel's collapse state from the panel title? In the following example:

```
<Panel>
    <Panel.Heading>
        <Panel.Title toggle>
            This is the title of the panel
            <i className="fa fa-angle-double-right" />
        </Panel.Title>
    </Panel.Heading>
    <Panel.Collapse>
        <Panel.Body>
            This is the body of the panel
        </Panel.Body>
    </Panel.Collapse>
</Panel>
```

I would like the font awesome `<i>` tag inside of the `Panel.Title` to change automatically between `fa-angle-double-right` and `fa-angle-double-down` when the panel is open, and switch back when it is closed. But I can't seem to access the panel's collapse state from the panel title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you link to seems to have the answer you're looking for.

You should be able to maintain some local state, `this.state.open`, and pass it as the `expanded` prop to the Panel.

```
class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);

    this.state = {
      // to share the state, we must maintain it ourselves
      open: true
    };
  }


  render() {
    const iconClass = this.state.open
      ? 'fa-angle-double-down'
      : 'fa-angle-double-right';

    return (
      <Panel id="example-1" expanded={this.state.open}>
        <Panel.Heading> 
          <Panel.Title
            onClick={() => this.setState({ open: !this.state.open})}>
            This is the title of the panel
            <i className={iconClass} />
          </Panel.Title>
        </Panel.Heading>
        <Panel.Collapse>
          <Panel.Body>
            This is the body of the panel
          </Panel.Body>
        </Panel.Collapse>
      </Panel>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I did see that in the docs but that seems, to me, more about controlling expanded state externally. I don't want to have to duplicate the checks that the panel makes to determine if it should be open in the checks that cause the arrow to reflect that open state. IMO, there should simply be a way to ask the panel its state (which is something the panel does know) when reflecting that state. I appreciate what you came up with, though, and will begin applying it unless something else is suggested. Thanks!

Comment: I guess in React all you can do is wrap up components with your own and have the lower ones reflect the wrapper’s state. So in the end, something like that example is what I ended up doing. Thanks